# how do I pass a variable from js file to laravel controller to make a query based on the variable taken from an element clicked

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

this is code in laravel controller

```
$data = table::where('field',$var)->get();
```

this is the js file im trying to receive the variable from to pass it to the query

```
function clicked(var)
{
    console.log(var);
}
```

Comment: You will need to use AJAX requests. There are tons of tutorials for that. E.g https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: You'll need an AJAX function, a route and a controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Front end will need to send data to the backend via a HTTP request.
This can be done via AJAX. There are good libraries that you can use to do this such as AXIOS if you are using Laravel with Vue.JS. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
axios.post('/URL_HERE', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative method I have chosen to go with. this is the js file:

```
var region = "regionInput";
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    });
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/test-route",
            //dataType:"jsonp",
           // dataType:"String",
            data:{regionName: region},
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

this is the web.php file

```
Route::post('/test-route',[App\Http\Controllers\regionsController::class, 'testMethod']);
```

this is the function in the controller

```
public function testMethod(Request $request){
  
  return response()->json($request->input("regionName"));
```